# UITableView not drawing Cells correctly "sometimes"

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, xcode6

When my app displays the table, sometimes, it displays ALL the content of the database. but when i try to segue to another VC an return from that VC (Lets say, I added a new entry to the Database), it displays this. if you touch below the "Missing" cells, it segue to the correct entry though...

I've already tried using:

[self.cTableView setNeedsDisplay];
[self.cTableView setNeedsLayout];
or
[self.cTableView beginUpdates];
[self.cTableView endUpdates];
or
[self.cTableView reloadData];

but still to no avail. Is there any way of refreshing the tableview graphically?

I can't post images due to reputations but the image that I'm going to post looks like the TableView gets CUT going down.

Image:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1336061/StackOverflow/Untitled.jpg

Comment: Does your new entry appear on the datasource of your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you re-using your cell correctly?
Check the cells reuse identifier. see that the cells are not being allocated every iteration (in cellForRow delegate).

Comment: Hummmm... I forgot to mention that I'm using a custom Cell from xib. I did check the Cell ID and upon looking at it, it was different. fixing this issue presented a new type of issue: [New Result Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1336061/StackOverflow/Untitled1.jpg)

Comment: Upon closer look at the custom CellView that I've created, it is using the same Cell Reuse ID. I changed some and it worked.... the issue now is refreshing the UITableView altogether.

Comment: first, check the array of items: that it still holds the items.
secondly, the code that updates the cells with the object/data should be called every iteration. (did you put it in the allocation block by accident?)

Comment: I was able to determine that the Reuse ID for my custom Cell is not being used. I'm now fixing that issue with the rest of the custom Cell :)

Answer (score 0):

If the objects that provide data to the "Data Source" of the table change, you might as well need to call:

```
[table reloadData];
```

OR

Load the new elements with their indexes (look at the UITableView headers to use the right delegate.

Comment: that's the thing, the data is there. i can touch an invisible cell and it will display the correct data. an image would be a best way to describe my issue. let me post it.

Comment: This does not look like a data problem, but more some UI problem. Are you using autolayout or some constrains? Try scrolling the view. If it scrolls will mean that something in the UI is wrong (not with the table data itself). If you're on iOS8 you should be able to inspect the view layers from the xib/storyboard on runtime

Comment: If you pause the debugger and type `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` does the tableview have the correct frame? Is there another view covering it? Alternatively have you tried xcode's view debugger? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html

Comment: Let me check. Auto-layout is not an issue because i can still scroll down. further down but the cells are not displayed. if i touch an empty space, it segue to a record. I'm now investigating further into how the Cells are being drawn.